# How to align circle with 2 pentagons in python using turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am asked to create a program that draws a circle with 2 pentagons:
one inside the circle with its vertices are on the circle.
the other is outside the circle with its sides tangent to the circle.

I was able to draw the shapes fairly easy, but my problem is aligning them up. Meaning the pentagons are not inside and outside the circle as I was asked.

I don't know much about python, and I feel that this kind of problem needs some math knowledge I do not have.

The code is attached and also a screen shot of what I am getting.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import random
import math
import re
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, mainloop
import sys

class KeysMouseEvents:
        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                global arg
                turtle.setup(width=800,height=500,startx=300,starty=250)
                self.T=Turtle()
                self.screen=self.T.getscreen()
                self.T.pensize(4)
                self.T.color("black")
                self.screen.onclick(self.drawconcfigs)
                self.screen.listen()
                self.count=0
                self.first=(0,0)
                self.T.hideturtle()
                self.T.up()
                self.screen.onkey(self.T.clear,"c")
        def drawconcfigs(self,x,y):
                #make turtle fastest speed
                self.T.speed(3)
                #initialize color list
                colorlist = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white', 'pink', 'brown', 'purple', 'gray', 'orange']
                #assign random colors for all three shapes
                outersqcolor = random.choice(colorlist)
                circlecolor = random.choice(colorlist)
                while circlecolor  == outersqcolor:
                        circlecolor = random.choice(colorlist)
                innersqcolor = random.choice(colorlist)
                extsquarerot = random.randint(0,90)
                #echo extsquarerot
                intsquarerot = random.randint(0,90)
                degToRads = 0.01745329251
                extsquarerot *= degToRads
                intsquarerot *= degToRads
                while (innersqcolor == circlecolor or innersqcolor == outersqcolor):
                        innersqcolor = random.choice(colorlist)
                #process mouse clicks
                self.count = (self.count + 1)
                if self.count == 1:
                        self.firstx=x
                        self.firsty=y
                        self.T.goto(x,y)
                        self.T.down()
                        self.T.dot()
                        self.T.up()
                        return
                if self.count == 2:
                        #draw rectangle first
                        self.secondx=x
                        self.secondy=y
                        self.T.goto(x,y)
                        self.T.down()
                        self.T.dot()
                        self.T.up()
                        self.count=0
                        X = self.secondx - self.firstx
                        Y = self.secondy - self.firsty
                        d = X * X + Y * Y
                        radius = math.sqrt (d)
                        #L = radius
                        L = math.sqrt(2 * radius * radius)
                        #upperleft = (self.firstx - L * math.cos(extsquarerot), self.firsty + L * math.sin(extsquarerot))
                        side=1.4*radius*math.sin(36)
                        self.T.color("black", outersqcolor)
                        self.T.goto(self.secondx,self.secondy)
                        self.T.right(extsquarerot/degToRads)
                        #self.T.goto(upperleft)
                        self.T.forward(radius)
                        #self.T.goto(self.firstx,self.firsty)
                        #self.T.right(135)
                        self.T.begin_fill()
                        self.T.down()
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.left(72)
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.left(72)
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.left(72)
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.left(72)
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.up()
                        self.T.end_fill()


                        #draw circle
                        X = self.secondx - self.firstx
                        Y = self.secondy - self.firsty
                        d = X * X + Y * Y
                        radius = math.sqrt (d);
                        self.T.goto(self.firstx, self.firsty-radius)
                        self.T.color("black", circlecolor)
                        self.T.begin_fill()
                        self.T.down()
                        self.T.setheading(0)
                        self.T.circle(radius)
                        self.T.up()
                        self.T.end_fill()
                        #draw square inside
                        a = math.sqrt (radius*radius/2)
                        upperleft = (self.firstx-a, self.firsty+a)
                        side=radius*math.sin(36)

                        #self.T.goto(upperleft)
                        self.T.color("black", innersqcolor)
                        self.T.goto(self.firstx,self.firsty)
                        self.T.left(intsquarerot/degToRads)
                        #self.T.goto(upperleft)
                        self.T.forward(radius)
                        #self.T.goto(self.firstx,self.firsty)
                        self.T.right(135)
                        self.T.begin_fill()
                        self.T.down()
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.right(72)
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.right(72)
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.right(72)
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.right(72)
                        self.T.forward(side)
                        self.T.right(72)
                        self.T.up()
                        self.T.end_fill()
                        self.T.goto(self.firstx,self.firsty)
                        self.T.down()
                        self.T.dot()
                        self.T.up()

        def main(self):
                mainloop()

def drawconcfigs():
        draw=KeysMouseEvents()
        draw.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        arg=sys.argv[0]
        drawconcfigs()
```

Thank you, [bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VFrX.png)

Comment: Inner Pentagon needs circle center and radius, precalulated angles between sides (always the same angles) and you have to only calculate side width. Other Pentagon need the same center and radius, precalulated angles between sides - you have to only calculate side width. Make functions which draw circle and pentagon using circle center point and radius so code wil be more readable.

Comment: now your function `drawconcfigs` is too long so nobody wants to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created functions so now code is more readable and then I could create working example.

Important elements:

In `pentagon()`

```
side = 2*(radius * math.sin(math.radians(36)))

self.T.setheading(0)
self.T.right(144)
```

and arguments

```
# draw outer figure
r = radius / math.cos(math.radians(36))
self.pentagon(self.first_x, self.first_y, r, self.outer_color)

# draw circle
self.circle(self.first_x, self.first_y, radius, self.circle_color)

# draw inner figure
r = radius
self.pentagon(self.first_x, self.first_y, r, self.inner_color)
```

Full working code:

```
import random
import math
import turtle

class KeysMouseEvents:

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        turtle.setup(width=800, height=500, startx=300, starty=250)

        self.T = turtle.Turtle()
        self.T.pensize(4)
        self.T.color("black")
        self.T.hideturtle()
        self.T.up()
        self.T.speed(3)

        self.screen = self.T.getscreen()
        self.screen.listen()
        self.screen.onkey(self.T.clear, "c")
        self.screen.onclick(self.on_click)

        self.color_list = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white', 'pink', 'brown', 'purple', 'gray', 'orange']
        #print('init')
        self.reset()
        self.select_colors()


    def main(self):
        turtle.mainloop()


    def reset(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.first_x, self.first_y = (0,0)
        self.second_x, self.second_y = (0,0)


    def select_colors(self):
        self.outer_color = random.choice(self.color_list)

        self.circle_color = random.choice(self.color_list)
        while self.circle_color  == self.outer_color:
            self.circle_color = random.choice(self.color_list)

        self.inner_color = random.choice(self.color_list)
        while self.inner_color in (self.circle_color, self.outer_color):
            inner_color = random.choice(self.color_list)


    def distance(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        dx = x2 - x1
        dy = y2 - y1
        d = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        return d


    def dot(self, x, y, color="black"):
        self.T.goto(x, y)
        self.T.color(color, color)

        self.T.down()
        self.T.dot()
        self.T.up()


    def circle(self, x, y, radius, color):
        self.T.goto(x, y-radius)
        self.T.color("black", color)

        self.T.setheading(0)

        self.T.begin_fill()
        self.T.down()
        self.T.circle(radius)
        self.T.up()
        self.T.end_fill()        


    def pentagon(self, x, y, radius, color):
        side = 2*(radius * math.sin(math.radians(36)))

        self.T.goto(x, y+radius)
        self.T.color("black", color)

        self.T.setheading(0)
        self.T.right(144)

        self.T.begin_fill()
        self.T.down()
        for x in range(5):
            self.T.forward(side)
            self.T.left(72)
        self.T.up()
        self.T.end_fill()


    def distance(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        dx = x2 - x1
        dy = y2 - y1
        d = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        return d


    def on_click(self, x, y):

        #process mouse clicks
        self.count += 1

        if self.count == 1:
            self.first_x = x
            self.first_y = y
            self.dot(x,y)
        elif self.count == 2:
            self.second_x = x
            self.second_y = y
            self.dot(x, y)

            # find radius    
            radius = self.distance(self.first_x, self.first_y, self.second_x, self.second_y)

            # draw outer figure
            r = radius / math.cos(math.radians(36))
            self.pentagon(self.first_x, self.first_y, r, self.outer_color)

            # draw circle
            self.circle(self.first_x, self.first_y, radius, self.circle_color)

            # draw inner figure
            r = radius
            self.pentagon(self.first_x, self.first_y, r, self.inner_color)

            # draw points                                 
            self.dot(self.first_x, self.first_y, "red")
            self.dot(self.second_x, self.second_y, "red")

            # reset data                         
            self.reset()
            self.select_colors()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #draw = KeysMouseEvents()
    #draw.main()
    KeysMouseEvents().main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a legend!